# WMI, negative CPU usage value and Timestamp_Sys100NS in past

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi

I am monitoring some machines using WMI, using .NET's `System.Management` stuff. The query I am using is this:

```
SELECT Timestamp_Sys100NS, PercentProcessorTime 
FROM Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor 
WHERE Name='_Total'
```

From that I compute the CPU usage % using the well known formula:

```
double cpu_usage = (1 - (double)delta_cpu / delta_time) * 100;
```

It works very well every machine but one (so far).

The problem is that for one machine, which is Windows 2003 server (with hyper-threading enabled, if it matters), I am sometimes getting negative CPU usage values. In other words, the `(double)delta_cpu / delta_time` expression yields number `> 1`. I did search the web for hints as to why this could be happening but I found nothing.

Is this Windows 2003 server specific? Or is it hyper-threading related problem? Or is it just expected and I should just clamp the CPU usage value or the `cpu_delta` value into some range?

*EDIT:*
The second weird thing I am observing with this one machine is that the `Timestamp_Sys100NS` value does not indicate `FILETIME` like date (ticks since epoch January 1, 1600) but instead it looks like ticks since boot time.

*EDIT 2*:
I have now verified that this problem is across a lot of Windows 2003 servers. And I am apparently [not the only one with the same problem](http://www.ureader.com/msg/14773088.aspx).

*EDIT 3*:
I have solved the time stamp issue by querying `LastBootUpTime` from `Win32_OperatingSystem` and adding that to the `Timestamp_Sys100NS` when the value of `Timestamp_Sys100NS` is too far in the past. That seems to give correct date and time. The code manipulating the date after it is retrieved from `Win32_OperatingSystem` looks like this:

```
WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime swbem_time = new WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime();
swbem_time.Value = date_str;
string time_as_file_time_str = swbem_time.GetFileTime(true);
return new DateTimeOffset(epoch.Ticks + long.Parse(time_as_file_time_str),
    swbem_time.UTCSpecified
    ? TimeSpan.FromMinutes(swbem_time.UTC)
    : TimeSpan.Zero);
```

...then adjust to UTC...

```
boot_time = boot_time.UtcDateTime;
```

...then is `boot_time` simply added to the time stamp (`current`) returned in by WMI in the `Timestamp_Sys100NS` field...

```
if (time.Year < 2000)
    time = boot_time + current;
```

*EDIT 4*:
It appears that there are 3 classes of system with respect to `Timestamp_Sys100NS`:

1. First are Vista+ system where the `Timestamp_Sys100NS` is time in ticks since epoch in UTC.
2. Second are some Windows 2003 systems where the `Timestamp_Sys100NS` needs to be added to `Win32_OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime` to get reasonable time.
3. Third class are systems where doing the above addition still results in a date days off of the right date and time.

*EDIT 5*: Some of the affected machines might have been VMs but not all of them.

Comment: It means the CPU is using YOU :)

Comment: How did you add LastBootUpTime to TimeStamp_Sys100NS? What kind of conversion did you do?

Comment: @raz3r: I am using the `System.DateTime(Int64)` ctor (takes ticks) and I add it to the LastBootUpTime. I will only be able to check the exact detail tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like a standard "time synchronization" issue to me.

your system's clock is...  a clock.   in your case, your clock may be running fast (perhaps it completes a minute in 99% of the actual time)  so when your computer syncs with an external clock (such as through the Windows Time service) your system time will jump backwards.

alternatively, the user may manually adjust the system time (eg: Date and Time control panel), so it's something you should design for (your users would be very unhappy if setting their system's time crashes your app!)

the way I solve this is by clamping.  always require at least 0.0 seconds of "real time" to pass, but also clamp to a maximum of 0.5 seconds, as time adjustment may leap forwards, not only backwards.

i hope that helps.

Comment: don't forget that a 0.0 second minimum means you need to watch out for divide-by-zeros too

Comment: i'm pretty sure this is your problem, so please msg back if my solution works, or if it ends up being something else  (assuming you read your month old question again)

Comment: The bad time information effect is consistent, it does not happen only once in a while but all the time. My code was checking like each 5 seconds. That seems long enough not to suffer from gradual time adjustment by NTP daemons/services. I do nothing that your answer explains the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code create application on that machine and see if you get the right readings 
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8572

Comment: The raw values are the same from both `System.Management` API and `wmic` and from the above tool.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are specifically talking about is PERF_100NSEC_TIMER_INV
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms803963.aspx

I have not personally dealt with this problem because I have never seen values below zero.

This is all I have been doing:

```
/// <summary>
/// PERF_100NSEC_TIMER_INV algorithm.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="n2"></param>
/// <param name="d2"></param>
/// <param name="n1"></param>
/// <param name="d1"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static int CalculatePerf100NsecTimerInv(long n2, UInt64 d2,
                                               long n1, UInt64 d1)
{
    int usage = 0;
    try
    {
        double dataDiff = (n2 - n1);
        double timeDiff = (d2 - d1);
        double dUsage = (1 - (dataDiff / timeDiff)) * 100;

        // Evaluate
        usage = (dUsage >= 0.5) ? Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(dUsage)) : 0;
    }
    catch { }

    // Return
    return usage;
}
```

Usage:

```
// Calculate
int cpuTime =
    MSPerformanceAlgorithms.CalculatePerf100NsecTimerInv(
        current.PercentProcessorTime, current.TimestampSys100Ns,
        previous.PercentProcessorTime, previous.TimestampSys100Ns);
```

If I watch the CPU usage on the task manager for the 2003 box, it matches fine. I think you can disregard anything less than zero as long as you are calculating with these values.

Comment: I am not sure there is much else you can do. From your findings, I would add a check to see if LastBootUpTime > Timestamp_Sys100NS as a direct indicator that the stamp is inaccurate.

There has been a lot of inconsistencies among the releases of WMI. They didn't really start to become overly effective until Windows 2003 with the addition of better Network data and counters. 

Is it possible this is only on Windows 2003 R1? Is there a difference in x86 vs x64? 

This is a great topic, and many of us could benefit from the result.